# Is it possible to insert a parameter from a method into a sqlite3 query?

Tags: python, methods, sqlite

I've got the following method that creates a database with the name I gave for `dbname` in the method and this works, but now I want the `tablename` parameter to be the name of the table I create in the `curs.execute` part.

```
def create_dbtb(self, dbname, tablename):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.tablename = tablename
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbname)
        curs = conn.cursor()

        curs.execute('''CREATE TABLE table(id INT, # So table should be changed by the parameter 'tablename'
                        gen TEXT, age INT, mar TEXT,
                        loc INT, inc INT, iscr INT, escr INT)''')
        conn.commit()
```

So when I use this method like this:

```
create_dbtb('data.db', 'data')
```

I want to create a database named `data.db` and within this database a table named `data`. Anyone who knows how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#module-string

Comment: Regular [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax): `"""CREATE TABLE {}(...)""".format(tablename)`

Comment: but dont use string formatting for regular queries params - read this http://bobby-tables.com/ for more.